# Django query filter contacts on time now()

Tags: django

**My question is:**

**Using the following query how can I get contacts that are due now()? ie all contacts at the time of running the view that have not been sent**

```
Contact.objects.filter(send_email_on=<WHERE TIME NOW???? , status='not sent')
```

Note I don't want future contacts juts ones not send up to now()

Comment: Is `send_email_on` a DateTimeField?

Comment: @Paulo Bu, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)    
Contact.objects.filter(send_email_on__lt=now , status='not sent')
```

Provided that `send_email_on` is a DateTimeField.
For the `lt`(less than) see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#lt).

Though I think you need to use [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) and [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

Comment: would it be send_email_on__gt>=now ?

Comment: yep, I'm using celery for this this will be inside a periodic tasks just did not want to confuse the question being asked.

Comment: silly question, You sure it's not less then?  would this bring all contacts greater then the current time i.e. future dates that are not due to be sent yet?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you may try with:

```
from datetime import datetime
# greater than or equal now(), change the __lte for whatever you need
Contact.objects.filter(send_email_on__lte=datetime.now(), status='not sent')
```

You can take a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) which is very helpful with *Field lookups strings*.

HINT:

1. **__lt** lower than
2. **__lte** lower than or equal
3. **__gt** greater than
4. **__gte** greater than or equal

Comment: you sure its not the other way around __lte=now otherwise I would get contacts that are not yet due to be sent.